# How to output, from JavaScript, JSON output so that it is recognized as JSON?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

**EDIT**: Following an exchange with guest271314, I realized that the wording of the questions (in the body of my question) may be misleading. I kept the old version stroked out and better reworded a new version

---

***Background:*** When getting JSON from remote servers, the response headers include a `Content-Type: application/json` entry which suggests to the browser to render the content as JSON. This enables [Chrome extensions](https://github.com/callumlocke/json-formatter) or native Firefox functionalities to format the output:

[image]

***My problem:*** I would like to get the same rendering (done by the browser) with JavaScript-provided JSON, by first fetching the content, and then pushing it into the DOM. This does not work, <del>I can only get a JSON string, rendered as a string.</del> the JSON is rendered as a string, and not formatted by the browser.

***My thoughts so far:*** it looks like I fail to

- output the JSON as a string without delimiters
- inform the browser that the content is JSON

The code I tried is the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- here I am trying to simulate the response headers so that the
    browser is hinted of the content type -->
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="application/json; charset=UTF-8"/>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='root'></div>
    <script>
        fetch('https://httpbin.org/get')
            .then(function (r) {
                if (r.ok) {
                    return r.json()
                }
                throw new Error('response was not ok: ' + r.statusText)
            })
            .then(function (text) {
                // here I am stringyfying the JSON Object and replacing a DOM
                // element with it (including the delimiters). The string is 
                // unfortunately quote-delimited
                document.getElementById('root').outerHTML = JSON.stringify(text)
            })
            .catch(function (err) {
                console.log(err)
            })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The effect on the same source:

[image]

**Is it possible <del>to achieve from JS the same effect as querying the source directly in the browser?</del> to have JavaScript-generated JSON being pretty-rendered by the browser own mechanisms (built-in or via an extension)?**

Comment: put it into an iframe maybe? or simply  redirect?

Comment: Since the browser has already received the response and decided what the content type is at this point you _might_ not be able to change it afterwards.

Comment: Not gathering what you are trying to achieve? _"here I am stringyfying the JSON Object"_ `JSON` is a string format, not an object. `.json()` converts `JSON` to a JavaScript object.

Comment: @Jonasw: That's a good idea but I will generate the JSON Object in my code

Comment: you need to contruct a tree view in DOM, you can use some library like `jstree` or something like that to make it easier

Comment: @guest271314: Yes, but with the right headers the browser may treat it in a special way (pretty-printing, collapsing). I gave an example for JSON fetched from a remote server (this feature  works) and one generated in my code (which does not work)

Comment: @WoJ _"Yes, but with the right headers the browser may treat it in a special way (pretty-printing, collapsing)"_ Not sure what you mean? You can use `JSON.stringify()` to pass JavaScript` object returned from `.json()` call. _"I gave an example for JSON fetched from a remote server (this feature works) and one generated in my code (which does not work)"_ What do you mean by "does not work"? Still not certain what expected result is? Are you trying to render `JSON` with indentation in `HTML` `document`?

Comment: @guest271314: can you see the difference in the screenshots? This is the  same source JSON, one fetched directly, the other one output via JS. `stringify()` works fine - it creates a string out of the JSON Object but, once it is in the DOM, it does not display the  same. Kim's answer suggests that it is too late for the extension to catch the chnaged content-type, this is probably the reason

Comment: @guest271314: to your last question: no, i am not trying to display a pretty-printed tree (there are good libraries for that), I am trying to understand why there is a difference in the rendering in both screenshots.

Comment: @WoJ Because the first screenshot is apparently rendered using appropriate `HTML` elements and `css`, as a feature of that partiular web site - similar to github. And the second screenshot renders the `JSON` string as `.textContent` or `.innerHTML` of `document.body`. There is no need for a library to "pretty print" `JSON`; `.stringify()` and `HTML` are capable of rendering indented, or "pretty-print" `JSON`. Note, `JSON` does not require any special formatting to be valid `JSON`.

Comment: @guest271314: yes, of course. What I meant is why the JSON in the first screenshot is rendered nicely and in the second one, as a string. They both come as a string and the extension (which is doing the formatting, adding the CSS, etc.) is properly handling the first one and not the second one. But as I mentioned, it is probably because in the second case it (the extension) does not see the content as JSON at all (and therefore does not fire up) as the content type is changed after it (the extension again) had its say in the rendering.

Comment: They are both the same string. Not sure about the implementation of the extension, or why an extension is necessary to render `JSON` in the manner that you are expecting. You are creating more work for yourself than is necessary to render expected result. You can use `<pre>` element or `css` `white-space:pre` and `JSON.stringify()` at `JavaScript` and be done with this inquiry. The first image appears to be rendered in same manner as a github repo which is not the "Raw" option; that is, appearing to be plain text, though actually `HTML` styled with `css`. The second is the un-styled string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, your browser extension cannot catch this. And I do not see any option. Headers are already sent, when the JavaScript has been executed, so I guess, your Extension is out of the game.

The stringify() function by the way works fine. What you want is a human readable output.

Have you thought of JavaScript code highlighters like

- https://highlightjs.org/
- http://prismjs.com/

There should be one that supports JSON rendering like your browser extension.

Comment: Thanks. I know that `.stringify()` works fine (never sait it was not) but that the output was not pretty-rendered. What you said about the extension being out of the game makes a lot of sense: even if I modified the effective `Content-Type`, it would be too late for it too see that.

Comment: By the way: If .stringify() would have an output that is human readable - the JSON would be damaged.

Comment: sure, I do not have anything against `stringify()` - my aim is to understand why the rendering is different (what caused the first pretty-printing firing up, as opposed to the second case where it did not fire up). The more I think about that, the more I believe that the extension is too early in the game (and cannot catch the content type hint pushed by JS)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your document is displayed as `text/html` while httpbin.org/get has `application/json` as document-type. You already used

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="application/json; charset=UTF-8"/>
```

but if you right click the page in firefox (chrome apparently does not have this option) and select view pageinformation (or something like that), the type is still `text/html` although the header in dev tool already shows `content-type: application/json`. Also, when you take a look at the Response in dev tools, your response is a html file while the response from httpbin.org/get is plain json with no body tag etc.

So I've tried to replace the whole html content with the json content:

```
document.documentElement.outerHTML = JSON.stringify(text)
// or
document.documentElement.outerHTML.replace(JSON.stringify(text))
```

But the first gives an error (`Modifications are not allowed for this document`). The second just replaces the whole content of `<body></body>` with the JSON data. But it still does not work. So unless you don't use a backend server that just retruns the JSON once the site is called, it won't be possible to use the browsers JSON viewer.

Another option would be to redirect:

```
window.location = "https://httpbin.org/get";
```

Answer (score 0):

If gather Question correctly you can use `<pre>` element to render `JSON` and use third parameter of `JSON.stringify()` for indentation

```
<pre id='root'></pre>
```

```
document.getElementById('root').textContent = JSON.stringify(text, null, 4)
```

Comment: Sorry if I was not clear enough in my question but (taking my last comment above)  I am not trying to display a pretty-printed tree (there are good libraries for that), I am trying to understand why there is a difference in the rendering in both screenshots.

Comment: The `JSON` at second screenshot appears to be loaded directly at `<body>` `.innerHTML`. The first screenshot appears to be an embedded application; at least including `css`. Though screenshots usually do provide adequate details. Can you create a plnkr with a version for each rendering that you are trying to describe? You cannot for `HTML` to be `JSON` or rendered as indented `JSON`; `JSON` is a string, and does not require indentation. A library is not necessary.  You can use the appropriate `HTML` element or `css` to render `JSON` formatted in a specific manner

Comment: @guest271314 The first site (httpbin.org/get) does not load the `JSON` in `<body>`. It does not have a tag at all and thats the point of it. JSON is just JSON. So You would have to replace the `<html>` tag with your JSON data. But that is (see my answer) not possible.

Comment: @guest271314: OK, I probably got the misunderstanding. I re-read my question and it indeed looked like I was trying to mimic (myself) the pretty-printing I get on the first screenshot. I reworded my question and added an edit info at the top.

Comment: @JonasDrotleff _"The first site (httpbin.org/get) does not load the `JSON` in `<body>`"_ That is not accurate. `JSON` is set as `.textContent` of a `<pre>` element when https://httpbin.org/get is loaded at address bar

Comment: @WoJ Again, you are creating a problem which does not need to exist. Use `<pre>` element or `css` `white-space:pre` and `JSON.stringify()` - if requesting `JSON` using `fetch()`, which converts `JSON` string to a JavaScript object - to render `JSON` string with the indentation that you are expecting.

Comment: @guest271314: I am not creating a problem (please re-read the question). I just want to understand why the rendering is different, specifically why the same JSON got interpreted differently. Please also read the answers which point to the same thing: that the content type, as seen by the browser, is different in the first case (headers push application/json) and in the other one (where my attempt to hint about application/json comes too late for the extension (or native browser mechanism) to be triggered). Again: *I am not trying to pretty print the output by myself*

Comment: @WoJ What do you mean by "why the rendering is different, specifically why the same JSON got interpreted differently"? The second example loads `html`, not `JSON`, yes? If an posted Answer to your inquiry resolves the presumptive issue you can accept that Answer. Not sure why you are trying to serve a `.html` file as `application/json`?

Comment: @guest271314: the first example what comes in though this call is HTML: some text + a header which states "this is JSON". The browser is free to do what he wants with this info - Chrome and the right extension pretty-formats it, FF does it natively. In the second case I also load a .html, initially empty (save the <script>) and then  put a JSON string there + a hint on the content via http-equiv. This is visible as a plain string. My question was: why petty-printed in one case and a string in the other? I believe that Kim's answer is the most correct so far (and to be eventually accepted)

Comment: Why "eventually accepted"? What is the delay if you have the Answer to your inquiry? From perspective here, if you are expecting a `JSON.string()` to be rendered with indentation, use `<pre>` and `JSON.stringify()`. Not sure how `fetch()` is related to Question at all?

Answer (score 0):

Serving JSON is done on the server side, not the the client side.

A HTML header of `Content-Type: application/json` does need to be sent along with the response but no HTML can be present in the response body.

I suggest looking into NodeJS and the Express library to get started building a server side javascript application.